# Using rand() in cpp & javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, random

So I am trying to convert this line of c++ code into javascript code

```
r = ((double)rand() / ((double)(RAND_MAX)+(double)(1))
```

However in c++ rand() returns a number between 0 and RAND_MAX and in javascript Math.random() returns a number between 0 and 1.

How do I adjust for such?

Comment: Heard of division? (hint: you're already doing it)

Answer (score 3):

The C++ code produces a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive), just like `Math.random()` does.

You can therefore just use `r = Math.random()` without further adjustment.

NB:  The `+ 1` in the C++ original is there to ensure that the upper bound is exclusive instead of inclusive, that being the usual convention for non-integer RNGs.

Comment: What about typcasting as a double? How is that done in javascript?

So in javascript it would just be r = Math.random(); ?

Comment: @user3775693 there's no need - all standard JS numeric values are intrinsically doubles.  So yes, just `r = Math.random()`.